# Delphi Remote Debugging in Windows container (rmtdbg###.exe ports)

Tags: docker, delphi, remote-debugging

We need a way to debug inside a Windows container image. The remote debugger (`rmtdbg270.exe`) uses one fixed port and additionaly a random port for each debugger attached. In the container (Docker) I only know how to map ports "static".

Does someone know how to:

1. setup `rmtdbg` on a set of limited ports, like 50100 to 50199, or
2. setup Docker (on Windows) to redirect ports of a specific application (Windows Server 2019 image), or
3. use an alternative Remote Debugger for Delphi IDE 10.4 and/or 11?

Comment: One option is to use the newer Platform Assistant which has other benefits like defining target profiles, better IDE integration and deploying files to the target for debugging.

Comment: I dont´know what u mean... We installed PaServer as it comes with the current 10.4. The PaServer invokes (under windows) the rmtdbg###.exe which can configure one port but spawns a new connection on a random port for each debugger. Is there a Other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Docker on Windows supports [the `-p` flag](https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports) to map container ports to host ports, you might consider as an alternative to employ a network proxy or a port forwarding tool within the container or on the host to manage the dynamic port mappings.

Tools like [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) or [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) could potentially be configured to handle such scenarios. This would involve having a proxy service running either in the container or on the host, which would manage the port mappings dynamically.
By setting up a proxy service to manage port mappings dynamically, it could act as a bridge between the IDE, [PAServer](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/PAServer,_the_Platform_Assistant_Server_Application), and `rmtdbg###.exe`, ensuring that the communication channels remain open and correctly mapped.

```
+-----------------------+    +----------------------+    +--------------------+
|       Host System     |    |     Docker Container |    |   Delphi Debugger  |
|                       |    |                      |    |                    |
| +------------+        |    | +------------+       |    | +---------------+  |
| |            |        |    | |            |       |    | |               |  |
| | Delphi IDE |        |    | |   socat    |       |    | | rmtdbg###.exe |  |
| |            |<-------|----|>| Instances  |<------|----|>|               |  |
| +------------+        |    | +------------+       |    | +---------------+  |
|                       |    |                      |    |                    |
+-----------------------+    +----------------------+    +--------------------+
```

- Delphi IDE initiates a debugging session to the fixed port on `rmtdbg###.exe`, which is mapped statically via Docker.
- `rmtdbg###.exe` spawns a new connection on a random port, which is captured by a `socat` instance within the Docker container.
- The socat instance forwards the connection between the random port within the Docker container and the corresponding port on the host system, establishing a bridge for the communication between the Delphi IDE and `rmtdbg###.exe`.
- The Delphi IDE and `rmtdbg###.exe` continue their debugging session over the established connections, with `socat` handling the dynamic port forwarding.

Configure Docker to map the known fixed port of `rmtdbg###.exe` to a port on the host machine using the `-p` flag during the `docker run` command.
For instance: `docker run -p 50000:50000 your-image-name`

Create and run a script `port-forward.sh` to launch `socat` instances that listen on a **range of ports** within the container and forward traffic to corresponding ports on the host.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the range of ports
START_PORT=50100
END_PORT=50199

# Loop through the range and create socat instances for port forwarding
for ((port=START_PORT; port<=END_PORT; port++)); do
    socat TCP-LISTEN:$port,fork TCP:localhost:$port &
done

# Keep the script running to maintain the socat instances
wait
```

Launch the Delphi remote debugger, `rmtdbg270.exe`, and connect to it from the IDE. The `socat` instances should handle the port forwarding for the range of ports specified.

Implement logging and monitoring to track the `socat` instances and ensure they are functioning as expected. This can also help diagnose any issues that arise during debugging.

This setup should create a bridge for the dynamically allocated ports, allowing for remote debugging within the container. Note that this setup assumes that the random ports allocated by `rmtdbg###.exe` fall within the specified range (50100 to 50199 in this example). It would be advisable to validate this setup in a controlled environment before deploying it in a production scenario.

---

> > `rmtdbg###.exe` spawns a new connection on a random port
>
> is this an outbound connection, from the Docker instance to the machine where the Delphi IDE is running?

Yes.

Based on the scenario you described, it seems likely that `rmtdbg###.exe` within the Docker container initiates an outbound connection to the machine where the Delphi IDE is running. When a debugging session is initiated, `rmtdbg###.exe` would need to establish a communication channel with the Delphi IDE.
That communication would facilitate the exchange of debugging information between the IDE and the debugger running within the Docker container.

In typical remote debugging setups, the debugger running on the remote machine (in this case, the Docker container) establishes an outbound connection to the machine hosting the IDE. That outbound connection allows the IDE to control the debugger, receive data from it, and send commands to it.

The diagram and the accompanying explanation you provided illustrate this flow well. The `socat` instances within the Docker container help bridge the communication between `rmtdbg###.exe` and the Delphi IDE across the network boundary imposed by Docker's network isolation. That setup allows the IDE on the host system to communicate with `rmtdbg###.exe` within the Docker container, despite the dynamic port allocation by `rmtdbg###.exe`.

> If I understand correctly, the machine where Delphi is running also must allow (accept) inbound connections from the Docker instance.

Yes, that is correct.

For the remote debugging setup to function properly, the machine where Delphi is running must accept inbound connections from the Docker instance. That is because when `rmtdbg###.exe` initiates a connection to the Delphi IDE for debugging, this connection is considered inbound from the perspective of the machine hosting the Delphi IDE.
So, any network firewalls or security policies present on the machine or within the network should be configured to allow these inbound connections on the specified ports.

Comment: `rmtdbg###.exe spawns a new connection on a random port` - is this an outbound connection, from the Docker instance to the machine where the Delphi IDE is running?

Comment: @mjn I have edited the answer to address your question

Comment: @VonC many thanks for the update. If I understand correctly, the machine where Delphi is running also must allow (accept) inbound connections from the Docker instance.

Comment: @mjn Yes. I have edited the answer to explain why.

Comment: @VonC I am not sure if the last update is correct. In A VPN / RDP environment, remote debugging worked after opening all TCP ports on the remote machine. I did not have to open any ports on my development machine. Maybe we can double-check this?

Comment: @mjn I missed the VPN aspect in your question. It is true that, in some network configurations, especially with certain VPN or reverse tunnel setups, it might not be necessary to explicitly open ports on the development machine. Instead, the network traffic is tunneled through existing connections or managed by the VPN infrastructure. I don't have much to suggest beside reviewing the network configuration (both on the Docker host and the development machine) and the configurations of `rmtdbg###.exe` and the Delphi IDE, o see if there are any settings that might explain the behavior observed.

Comment: @VonC I will check on the remote system 
wether rmtdbgxxx.exe opens an additional random port, and listens on it for incoming connections from the IDE.

Comment: My Docker guy approved of the Solution. Thanks

Comment: @Quelltextknecht If you or your "Docker guy" have any more questions, put them here on Stack Overflow (no bounty needed), and leave a comment here with the link to the new question.